# Using WPML wordpress with Multilingual laravel application as subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, url-scheme, wpml

I have a multilingual laravel application. My url structure like that:

`https://example.com/`**en**`/paths`

`https://example.com/`**es**`/paths`

I installed wordpress in `/public/blog`. It is working successfully.

I also installed WPML plugin in wordpress then url structure was like this,

`https://example.com/blog/`**en**`/blog-paths`

`https://example.com/blog/`**es**`/blog-paths`

So my first URL structure is broken. This is a situation I would not prefer for SEO.

Any advice on how to install wordpress inside Laravel application, keeping the multilingual url structure?

I want to result url structure like this instead of above schemes,

`https://example.com/`**en**`/blog/blog-paths`

`https://example.com/`**es**`/blog/blog-paths`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to install Wordpress inside public folder of your Laravel app that is in charge of responding to example.com via `app/public/index.php`

Thus, every request to `app/public/blog/` will be handled by WordPress.

Imho, this setup save your current url structure and do not interfere in any way.

Probably you have to adjust your Nginx config, but that is another question.